# Spring Integration: Adding additional Headers parameters to HTTP outbound request.

Tags: java, spring-integration

I'm trying to create a simple application in which user will enter any key and system will send a get request. I want to add some Custom headers to this GET request. In plain java i use following code.

```
URL url= new URL(CMRAuth.RESOURCE);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("OData-Version", "4.0");
        connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+cmrAuth.getAuthenticationResult().getAccessToken());
        System.out.println("code:"+connection.getResponseCode());
```

And It works fine. I want to do this with Spring-Integration outbound gateway. This is how my xml looks like.

```
<int-stream:stdin-channel-adapter id="consoleIn"
    channel="requestChannel">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</int-stream:stdin-channel-adapter>
<int:channel id="requestChannel" />

<int:chain input-channel="requestChannel">
    <int-http:outbound-gateway
        url="https://example.com"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String" http-method="GET"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="accountResponseHandler" />
</int:chain>
```

I want to give it all these extra headers: Accept, OData-Version, Authorization etc
How its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure those headers via `<header-enricher>` just before the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`. Maybe even in the same `<chain>`.

After that the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` has to be configured with the `header-mapper` as a reference to `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.outboundMapper()` bean. And that last one must be configured with the `userDefinedHeaderPrefix = null` and `outboundHeaderNames` with all desired headers to map.

Comment: I was declaring <header-enricher> outside <chain>. Thats why it was not working. Thanks